# OpenLayers - Activate ol.control function

Tags: javascript, controls, openlayers

I would like to activate my `ol.control.ZoomToExtent` function as if it was clicked on. Giving the variabele an id and then using `"id".click();` does not work. Neither does `variable.click();`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
var zoomToSearch = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
    extent: "",
    className: 'zoomToSearch',
    zoom: 10
});

zoomToSearch.id = "zoomToSearchId"

map.addControl(zoomToSearch);

function() {
    zoomToSearch.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to simulate a click on the control's button element

```
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomToSearch')[0];
  var button = element.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  button.click();
```